# How to reuse top activity from notification created using startForeground?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-notifications

I have a service that when the user performs an action it's changed to run in the foreground using [Service.startForeground(..)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29) since killing it would be disruptive to the user.

I build a notification using the following code to create its pending intent:

```java
Intent topActivityIntent = new Intent(this, topActivityClass);
// Rebuild the task stack
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
// Adds the back stack
stackBuilder.addParentStack(topActivityClass);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(topActivityIntent);
for (int i = 0; i < stackBuilder.getIntentCount(); i++) {
    Intent currentIntent = stackBuilder.editIntentAt(i);
    // Set flags to tell that we want to re-use the existing
    // topActivity if possible
    currentIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | 
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | 
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
}
// Adds the Intent to the top of the stack
// Gets a PendingIntent containing the entire back stack
PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

`topActivityClass` is the activity that the user is currently seeing since I would him/her to come back to the same activity.

The issue here is that when the user taps on the notification a new `Activity` is created instead of using the one in the task stack.

I have tried setting the flags only to the `topActivityIntent` and several combinations of flags.

What flags should I use to avoid creating new activities? Is it possible to re-use activities that are in the stack?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` from intent and it will reuse existing task